# PHP if else - Trying to choose from 3 potential values

Tags: php, if-statement

```
echo $link['Theme'];
 if(empty($link['Theme']))
 global $Theme;
 { echo $Theme; };
 if(empty($Theme))
 { echo 'default'; };
```

`$link` pulls data from the database. `$Theme` is an optional variable on a higher page that I would really like to have as an override for the Theme stored on the database.

Currently, I set it up to print the `$Theme` if the Theme from the database is NULL.

I tried adding another if statement for if there was no value in `$Theme`, it would simply print 'default' to load the default design.

Currently the last if statement makes it print `$link['Theme'}` + default (like spacedefault instead of just space or default)

Can someone help me with this? I'm not great at php yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the following conditionals

```
global $Theme;
if (empty($link['Theme'])) {
  if (empty($Theme)) {
    echo 'default';
  } else {
    echo $Theme;
  }
} else {
  echo $link['Theme'];
}
```

Here it is in two lines of code, if you're looking to use inline conditionals

```
global $Theme;
echo empty($link['Theme']) ? (empty($Theme) ? 'default' : $Theme) : $link['Theme'];
```

Comment: The inline one worked to make sure it prints default if there's no database value! Thanks. Any way I can modify it to make the `$Theme` an override of the dB value?

Comment: Had the original conditional round the wrong way, fixed.

Comment: Ah, awesome. I understand the top one much better. I swapped out `$link['Theme']` and `$Theme`, this allowed `$Theme` to override the other 2 if it has a value. Thanks a lot!

Comment: nested tertiaries kill kittens

Comment: It's only presented as an option ...

Comment: I'm with @lynks on this one. I just hope that I never have to maintain your code. Nested ternaries, ugh. Also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/28314/74429